# ASP.NET 6 + Identity + Sqlite, services.AddDbContext() how?

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am using a tutorial for ASP.NET Core 5.0 + SQL Server, but I am actually using ASP.NET Core 6.0 + Sqlite.

The tutorial has the following code in `StartUp.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
{  
    services.AddControllers();  
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnStr")));  
}
```

but in my project, that file or class does not exist. There is a `Program.cs` file that has no classes or methods but just lines of code. I guessed that it is what is replacing that class, so I tried to  use it

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options=> options.);
```

`options` had no such method like `UseSqlServer`. I thought that it is because I am using Sqlite, not SQL Server, so I searched the web for an example for Sqlite but the methods that those example did not exist either. I can see `AddEntityFrameworkSqlite`, but that was about it.

How can I make this work?

I have added the following relevant packages:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Other classes are the same as [the original tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net-5-with-jwt-and-swagger/).

Here is the `DbContext` class.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class ApplicationDbContext:IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options):base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

The `Program.cs` code I was trying to edit:

```
using WebApplication1.Authentication;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options=> options.);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: You have no `Startup.cs` file? Did you use the console app template by accident?

Comment: As for `options.UseSqlServer`, that won't work for SQLite at all. You need to install the [EF Core SQLite provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).

Comment: @DavidG No, I had chosen the ASP.NET API project, you know, the thing with the Weather API. Although, the output type was set to "Console Application". I had installed ..Sqllite.Core. After seeing you comment, I installed the ...Sqlite version, too. I will test a bit if that works.

Comment: I don't know whether it is a bug of VS 2022 Preview or not, but when I had typed `protected override void ` and pressed Ctrl+Shift, there was no `OnConfiguring` in the IntelliSense, so I thought it would not compile, but it compiled. After some testing, it seems that `OnConfiguring` shows up in the list if I type `override void `, but not `protected override void `.

Comment: If you're running VS2022 preview, then you might be using the new templates, and you should have mentioned that in the first place. That's not a finished product yet.

Comment: It seems you forget to add package. [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/6.0.0-preview.7.21378.4).

Comment: Experienced the same issue i am working with .net6.0 but project is initially setup using .net5. This worked for me - try this: https://medium.com/executeautomation/asp-net-core-6-0-minimal-api-with-entity-framework-core-69d0c13ba9ab

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Referring to [ASP.NET Core 6.0 Minimal API with Entity framework core](https://medium.com/executeautomation/asp-net-core-6-0-minimal-api-with-entity-framework-core-69d0c13ba9ab) provided by @ussimandias which also worked for me.

#### Packages needed:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

#### In `DbContext.cs`,

> override the `OnConfiguring` method to read the connection string of database from SQL server via `appsettings.json` file

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDb");
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }
```

#### In `Program.cs`,

> Set Dependency Injection with service container

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDb");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<EmployeeDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

## Entity Framework Database update via dotnet-ef

On Nuget Package Manager Console (Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Console):

- Install dotnet-ef tool: `dotnet tool install dotnet-ef -f`.
- Add database: `dotnet ef database update`
- Add migration: `dotnet ef database update`

Migration script created:

```
namespace MiniDemo.Migrations
{
    [DbContext(typeof(EmployeeDbContext))]
    [Migration("20210725025828_initialDb")]
    partial class initialDb
    {
        protected override void BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("Relational:MaxIdentifierLength", 128)
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "5.0.8")
                .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

            modelBuilder.Entity("MiniDemo.Model.Employee", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<string>("EmployeeId")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(450)");

                    b.Property<string>("Citizenship")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                    b.HasKey("EmployeeId");

                    b.ToTable("Employee");
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should not be answer, OP is asking SQLite, not MSSQL. it is not unable DB migration , it about make the DBContext to handle SQLite connection.

Comment: Thanks ytan11 !! After days looking for the solution, it has worked perfectly for me! I neeed joint Identity with my context and i only can login in my app, but context aren't found after login. The problem was in the lines of the context file, in .net 7 <code>protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Name=ConnectionString"); </code> dont run.

Answer (score 16):

You have to install those packeges

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

In Program.cs

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

In appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.;Database=;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

Comment: var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

Answer (score 0):

add db context - public StudentDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
{

```
    }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

Comment: This answer, which shows a code fragment of a constructor for `StudentDbContext`, does not seem to address the question, which asks where to call `services.AddDbContext()` in the context of an "ASP.NET 6 + Identity + Sqlite" project that does not have a `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method in `StartUp.cs`.  The question also does not have classs `StudentDbContext` or `Student`.  Might you please [edit] your question to clarify?  Thanks!  -[From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/33340143).

Answer (score 0):

This was **NOT** working for me :

```
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

But this was **OK** :

```
services.AddSqlServer<ApplicationDbContext>(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
```